# htaccess is not working for query page

Tags: .htaccess

I need to fetch the page

`http://localhost/Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/?view=clinics`

`http://localhost/Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/clinics`

I wrote this htaccess for this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/?view=$1 [L]
```

it is working, But i don't want the .html in the url.

Means, it is working on this url

`http://localhost/Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/clinics.html`

But i need in this url

`http://localhost/Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/clinics`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the **.html** from your rule's pattern so that you can access the uri without .html .

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ /path/?view=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you just give link to get understand the htaccess. Because i cant understand the + and * difference

Comment: * or + are more or less the same. Diffrence is that * means to match zero or more time whereas + means to match one or more time. I changed * to + to avoid rewriting empty requests.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to remove `/.html` from your RewriteRule. So it would become this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/?view=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess seems to be in `/Magnigeeks/noqdoc/dashboard/` directory hence you don't need to use this in target.

Also you must skip files and directories from your rewrite to avoid rules looping.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ ?view=$0 [L,QSA]
```